# Consistent full Horn theories of two structures

Tags: logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

Suppose that two structures $A$ and $B$ *whose cardinality is greater than 1* (added in a revision) have the same positive primitive theory.  Does it follow that the union of the full Horn theory of $A$ and that of $B$ is consistent?  (Here I allow possibly empty finite conjunctions in the antecedent of a basic Horn formula and  $\bot$ in the consequent; also a Horn sentence can have an arbitrarily many quantifiers.)

One way of having a contradiction from two Horn theories is having a sentence in one and its negation in the other.  Such a sentence is positive primitive (or negations thereof).  Hence the question in the beginning.  In fact, it is true of any concrete structures that I   can think of.

Comment: I presume the full Horn theory of $A$ is the set of all Horn sentences true in $A$. But can a Horn sentence have arbitrary alternations of quantifiers, or is it a universally quantified Horn clause?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I meant the former option; I will amend my question.

Comment: There is still something wrong with the question. You might want to specify exactly what form of sentence you mean by "p.p." or "Horn". Otherwise, please explain why a sentence from one Horn theory whose negation belongs to another Horn theory must be p.p.

Comment: Doesn't $(\mathbb{Z},<)$ and $(\mathbb{N},<)$ give a counterexample?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Even in the language $\{<\}$ as opposed to $\{\le\}$?

Comment: Take $A$ to be the $1$-element unstructured set and $B$ to be the $2$-element unstructured set. There are homomorphisms in both directions, so they satisfy the same p.p. sentences. The Horn sentence that separates them is $(\exists x)(\forall y)(x=y)$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I am sorry I'm saying this now, but I had assumed that my structures were nontrivial (non-singletons).  My sincerest apologies.

Comment: OK, then take $A$ to be a complete irreflexive graph on an infinite set and take $B$ to equal $A$ union a single isolated point. $A$ and $B$ are mutually embeddable, so the satisfy the same p.p sentences. The Horn sentence that separates them is $(\forall x)(\exists y)(E(x,y))$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes  That works, and if you decide to make it into answer, I'll accept it.  (By embeddable, you mean the graph-theoretic (?) notion, not the model-theoretic one, right?)

Comment: @KeithKearnes The only way I have thought of far is using the trichotomy of total orders, which I don't even believe is Horn.

Comment: @Pteromys: Regarding Alex's suggestion, $(\mathbb Z,<)$ and $(\mathbb N,<)$ have the same finitely generated substructures up to isomorphism so they satisfy the same p.p. sentences. Now you need an example of a Horn sentence that is true in $(\mathbb Z,<)$ and false in $(\mathbb N,<)$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I believe I have a variant of Alex's counterexmaple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I stated a misunderstanding of mine in my original post: arbitrarily quantified literals also have as their negations Horn sentences.  This explains Dr Alex Kruckman's examples on strict total orders and Professor Keith Kearnes's example on graphs.

Secondly, here is an example involving total orders in the language $\{\le\}$.  Consider again naturals and integers.    The chain of natural numbers satisfy the Horn sentence $(\exists x)(\forall y)[y \le x \to y = x]$, where as the chain of integers satisfy the Horn sentence $(\forall x)(\exists y)[y \not \ge x]$.  Now the theory of *partial* orders is Horn, so it suffices to show that no *partial* order satisfies those two Horn sentences.  This is easy, as the minimum element of a partial order, if it exists, cannot have an element strictly below it or an element incomparable with it.